# IP Tables, does it really need those rules?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I am just starting with IPTables, and I am wondering if I really have to create so many rules for a simple setup:

DMZ (Reverse Proxy) port 80 + 443
Frontend Subnet: Apache Webserver

The Reverse Proxy should be available on Port 80
Reverse Proxy outbound to the Internet on Port 443 (download updates)
Apache reachable from DMZ on Port 80
Apache Outbound to Internet on Port 443 (download updates)

In theory, I would create those rules now:

Reverse Proxy

- Accept INPUT from "www" to Port 80 - Established, New
- Accept OUTPUT to "www" with Port 80 - Established
- Accept OUTPUT to "www" with Port 443 - Established, New
- Accept INPUT on Port 443 - Established
- Accept OUTPUT to Frontend with Port 80 - Established, New
- Accept INPUT from Frontend on Port 80 - Established

Apache

- Accept INPUT from DMZ to Port 80 - Established, New
- Accept OUTPUT to DMZ with Port 80 - Established
- Accept OUTPUT to "www" with Port 443 - Established, New
- Accept iNPUT from "www" with Port 443 - Established

Question: Is this correct, or is this to complicated and I miss some more easy going way.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Question: Is this correct, or is this to complicated and I miss some more easy going way.